# Generating encryption_key Concourse

Tags: concourse

Reading

```
[...} 16 or 32 byte AES key [...]
```

(http://bosh.io/jobs/atc?source=github.com/concourse/concourse#p=encryption_key)
I was expecting

```
$ openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -k my_super_secret -P -md sha1
salt=7DE7F5AAA98A1E52
key=3C2293866568D49DFF5A8D85611E3A717AF09F08E7DE85B145E17547CB14B0DC
iv =7399712748AB8A677DC1056FD8888FC6

encryption_key: 3C2293866568D49DFF5A8D85611E3A717AF09F08E7DE85B145E17547CB14B0DC
```

to work in bosh configuration. But after configuration, atc doesn't come up again. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your key is too long. Try `openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -k my_super_secret -P -md sha1`

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell me why? I mean 32 byte are 256 bit, which would be aes-256. Were is my failure?

Comment: I did the same thing haha, I think the documentation is wrong.

Comment: @ElGohr, each character is 1 byte. So you want 32 characters, your key had 64.

Comment: Note that only [A-Z][0-9] characters are created with openssl here, which significantly weakens the encryption compared to a larger range (including lower case alpha, special characters). You want to use as many characters as allowed. Relatedly see: https://github.com/concourse/concourse/issues/1410